# Avoid panel to autoHide in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, panel

I am actually trying to develop a Firefox extension using the high level apis, and specifically trying to avoid a panel to autohide when you pick a file or when you click outside of the panel itself.

Does somebody has an idea of how to do this?

I know that it is possible using XUL, so why is this not easy using the apis?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Manny42 and @Noitidart: It is not in the API because `Panel()` based UI elements are intended for *temporary* use only.  Only *one* panel created with `Panel()` is permitted to be open at a time across *all* Add-on SDK extensions installed in that profile. **If another Add-on SDK extension opens a `Panel()`, yours will close.** It is specifically programmed this way in [the API source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/addon-sdk/source/lib/sdk/panel.js#114), and I have tested/verified. For more information see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38294913/3773011).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the offical sdk method of doing it:

```
let myPanel = Panel({.....})

let { getActiveView }=require("sdk/view/core");
getActiveView(myPanel).setAttribute("noautohide", true);
```

Comment: Well thank you for the effort, this SDK is killing me right now... I wonder if we can ask Mozilla... Or fill a bug report... Well thanks again!

Comment: ok no problem, by the way its messy and all, you know where i have that comment where i say its probably the last child but i want to verify. you dont have to do all that verification of adding event listenr and stuff, just get the recent window, and go     "var panelsInMainpop = aDOMWindow.document.querySelectorAll('#mainpopupset panel'); var myPanel = panelsInMainpop[panelsInMainpop.length-1];"

Comment: i suggest just put the widget in there with the sdk and on click of it create your own panel, what do you think?

Comment: i posted here asking for help: https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=16038

Comment: also manny do you want to do this non-sdk way? most of the code is common copy paste code i can make a demo for you later this week

Comment: I have a lot of code in the real project but is this possible to use this way just to generate the panel, meaning that I don't have to recode my whole project?

Comment: yea easily man. if u post up your whole project i can tell you for sure though how easy it is. i might be able to patch it for you in 15min but plz be detailed on what you need done

Comment: mod please delete this solution and unhide the deleted solution

Comment: Is there a modern way to do this using browser APIs or any other workaround? The SDK was deprecated according to MDN

Comment: Im not familar @guido732 I havent been involved, you would need to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Idea from
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192379/link-add-on-sdk-panel-to-toolbar-button)

```
var toolbarbuttonPanel = doc.createElement('panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.setAttribute('id', 'toolbarbutton-panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.setAttribute('type', 'arrow');
toolbarbuttonPanel.setAttribute('noautohide', 'true'); // This is important

var toolbarbuttonLabel = doc.createElement('label');
toolbarbuttonLabel.setAttribute('value', 'toolbarbutton panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.appendChild(toolbarbuttonLabel);

var mainPopupSet = document.querySelector('#mainPopupSet');
mainPopupSet.appendChild(toolbarbuttonPanel);
```

Then add this on sdk action/toggle button click:

```
toolbarbuttonPanel.openPopup(btn);
```

And [Noitidart's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192379/link-add-on-sdk-panel-to-toolbar-button#comment33713310_22197866)