# Auto width widget

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a small add-on to Firefofx, in which I use widgets. I wonder how to set auto-width which adapts to content. For example I want my widget to display numbers, which will have a different length. I can set my widget width but how do I know how much my number takes pixels. Is there a way to get the width, choosing automatically?
Here is some of my code:
My widget (my add-on uses other widgets),

```
//ROBOTS META
var robots_meta = widgets.Widget({
 id: "robots_meta",
 label: "Displays information about robots meta",
 content: "Meta-robots n/a",
 width: 100
});
```

Here is function that update content of my widget:

```
function meta_robots_checker(tab) {
  var meta_robots_w = robots_meta.getView(tab.window);
  meta_robots_w.content = 'Meta-robots n/a';
  worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("js/meta-checker.js")
   });
worker.port.emit("check_noindex");
worker.port.on('content', function(message) {    
        message = message.toLowerCase();
        message = message.replace('nofollow', '<span style="color:red">nofollow</span>');
        message = message.replace('noindex', '<span style="color:red">noindex</span>');
        meta_robots_w.content = message;
       //HERE MY WIDGET WIDTH SHOULD BE CHANGED
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to dynamically control the width, the widget is a panel. not a dynamically change width element like a label.

to get the widget panel element use "Element Selector" addon with "Dom Inspector".

See this topic here:
[Avoid panel to autoHide in Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509460/avoid-panel-to-autohide-in-firefox-extension/21599651?noredirect=1#comment32726559_21599651)

Comment: I know that I can change the width of widget dynamically but how to calculate it?

Comment: go through the children in the panel and do a ```child[i].getBoundingClientRect().width``` and get the max value from there and set it to the panel. if you post your addon simplified i can do it for u

Comment: you dont have access to the xul element that is the panel attached to the widget, have to get that first, follow the steps to use "Element Selector" and DOM Inspector. Otherwise post a simplified test case of your addon and ill look at it

Comment: Where can I post "simplified test". I don't want send all of my code until it is ready.

Comment: you can make a github account and upload there, or you can upload it anywhere like 4shared or even email me

Comment: I would be very grateful if you give me your e-mail, I can't find it

Comment: My email should show on my profile thats weird let me take a look.