# Link add-on SDK panel to toolbar button

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The add-on SDK attaches panels to widgets as seen [here](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6599/text-entry-panel.png). I would like to achieve the same effect **using the add-on SDK** with a toolbar button instead.

The toolbar button I'm using is of the [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/toolbarbutton.type) *menu-button*, which means that the left side is an icon and has an `oncommand` listener. The right side is a drop-down arrow which shows its contents on click. Here's the code to create such a button with the add-on SDK:

```
const doc = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;

var navBar = doc.getElementById('nav-bar')
var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
btn.setAttribute('id', 'hylytit');
btn.setAttribute('type', 'menu-button');
btn.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1');
btn.setAttribute('image', data.url('resources/hylyt_off.png'));
btn.setAttribute('orient', 'horizontal');
btn.setAttribute('label', 'Hylyt.it');
btn.addEventListener('command', function(event) {
  if (event.button===0) btnClick();
  console.log(TAG+'button clicked');
}, false);
var panel = doc.createElement('panel');
panel.setAttribute('id', 'search-panel');
panel.addEventListener('command', function(event) {
    console.log(TAG+'dropdown clicked');
}, false);
var label = doc.createElement('label');
label.setAttribute('control', 'name');
label.setAttribute('value', 'Article List');
var textbox = doc.createElement('textbox');
textbox.setAttribute('id', 'name');
panel.appendChild(label);
panel.appendChild(textbox);
btn.appendChild(panel);
navBar.appendChild(btn);
```

The `panel` above is not an add-on SDK panel, it's a [XUL panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/panel) and is severely limited in that it can't be styled with CSS. On top of this, the panel's `onCommand` listener never fires despite the fact that the `btn`'s `onCommand` fires as expected. The XUL panel shows itself when I click the dropdown button (as long as it has children), but because I can't access its click handler, I can't just create an add-on SDK panel on click.

So my question is this. Is there a way to access the toolbar button's menu portion's click handler or is there a way to append an add-on SDK panel as a child of a toolbar button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thanks for pointing me in the direction of arrow panels. Is there a way to place an HTML file in one rather than having to dynamically create XUL elements? The effect I'm trying to achieve is similar to the Pocket extension, which does one thing when the button part is clicked and another when the arrow is clicked. –  willlma 7 hours ago

You have 900+ rep, you should know better. It is common knowledge to create another question topic rather then ask how to do something different in a comment especially after solution acceptance.

Nonetheless, this is what you do to accomplish the Pocket toolbarbutton effect. Based on code supplied by contributor above.
Ask another question and I'll move this there and you can accept my solution there.

```
var doc = document;

var navBar = doc.getElementById('nav-bar')
var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
btn.setAttribute('id', 'hylytit');
btn.setAttribute('type', 'menu-button');
btn.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1');
btn.setAttribute('image', 'data:image/png;base64,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');
btn.setAttribute('orient', 'horizontal');
btn.setAttribute('label', 'Hylyt.it');
////
var toolbarbuttonPanel = doc.createElement('panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.setAttribute('id', 'toolbarbutton-panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.setAttribute('type', 'arrow');
var toolbarbuttonLabel = doc.createElement('label');
toolbarbuttonLabel.setAttribute('value', 'toolbarbutton panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.appendChild(toolbarbuttonLabel);
////
////
var dropmarkerPanel = doc.createElement('panel');
dropmarkerPanel.setAttribute('id', 'dropmarker-panel');
dropmarkerPanel.setAttribute('type', 'arrow');
var dropmarkerLabel = doc.createElement('label');
dropmarkerLabel.setAttribute('value', 'dropmarker panel');
dropmarkerPanel.appendChild(dropmarkerLabel);
////

navBar.appendChild(btn);

var mainPopupSet = document.querySelector('#mainPopupSet');
mainPopupSet.appendChild(dropmarkerPanel);
mainPopupSet.appendChild(toolbarbuttonPanel);

btn.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
    console.log('event.originalTarget',event.originalTarget);
    if (event.originalTarget.nodeName == 'toolbarbutton') {
        dropmarkerPanel.openPopup(btn);
    } else if (event.originalTarget.nodeName == 'xul:toolbarbutton') {
        toolbarbuttonPanel.openPopup(btn);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I marked the answer as correct after his comment about the iframe, which is similar enough to an add-on SDK panel for me to consider it a solution to the original question. If I make the iframe a child of the panel, it shows on click despite not having access to a click listener. 
That said, your solution is better because now that I have a two separate click events, I can do whatever I want when them. I'm going to accept this answer right here because [apparently it isn't frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon). Many thanks.

Comment: Appending an iframe was the solution to your question? No your question was clearly not answered by "append iframe"... Changing answers is not but lying is. No where in your question is it stated you want a dual panel toolbar button. My solution was an answer to your question in your comment.... You accepted an answer for a question posed in a comment... This is very much frowned upon. Learn some common SO etiquette from this.

Comment: Sure it is. If I want an add-on sdk panel (which is similar to a XUL panel that can load an HTML file) when I click the menu button, then *add an iframe as a child to panel* is a decent answer. He messed up by placing `panel.openPopup(btn)` in the event listener, but if you remove that line and add an iframe to the panel, then you get the desired behaviour: two seperate clicks, one of which shows a panel with HTML attached to the toolbar-button.

Comment: As for your edit, I don't want two panels, but who cares? You showed me and everyone who visits this page in the future a way to do one thing on button click and another on menu click. That solved my problem. I'm now going to use `if (event.originalTarget.nodeName == 'toolbarbutton')` to do a specific function that has nothing to do with a panel and `else if (event.originalTarget.nodeName == 'xul:toolbarbutton')` to show an add-on SDK panel. Your answer helps me solve **my original question** without difficulty, so I don't see why this is against etiquette. So go thank yourself.

Comment: lol you need to calm down willma accept your mistake. dont say others messed up when you dont understand whats going on, take a look at where the openPopups are. glad to see firefox addon dev tho. also glad to see so new users teach older ones a lesson in etiquette. props to blargh definitely deserve another up vote from me. i have edite this topic so people in future can reference it by "double/dual function toolbar button"

Comment: @Blargh i'm going to upload this to snippet to my gist section, its a great tutorial let me know what you think. i like your open source approach, and now its my turn to take from you haha

Comment: @Noitidart yes I copied your code and modified. Sure mate take it for tutorial we're open source here. willma share the modification you made to it so others can learn. How much do I have to teach you..... Im not responding to your ridiculous comments.

Answer (score 2):

Panels don't have an onCommand method see [MDN - Panels Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/panel)

You can make your panel stylized, give it type arrow like `panel.setAttribute('type', 'arrow')` and then to attach to your button. I didn't give it type arrow below.

Heres the working code. Copy paste to scratchpad and set Environment > Browser then run it.

```
var doc = document; //to put this back in sdk do const doc = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;

var navBar = doc.getElementById('nav-bar')
var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
btn.setAttribute('id', 'hylytit');
btn.setAttribute('type', 'menu-button');
btn.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1');
btn.setAttribute('image', ''); //i made this image blank because i dont have the image and im running from scratchpad
btn.setAttribute('orient', 'horizontal');
btn.setAttribute('label', 'Hylyt.it');

var panel = doc.createElement('panel');

btn.addEventListener('command', function(event) { //moved this below var panel = doc.createElement because panel needs to be crated before we write this function
  //if (event.button===0) btnClick();
  //console.log(TAG+'button clicked'); //what is TAG? its undefeined for me
    panel.openPopup(btn);
}, false);

panel.setAttribute('id', 'search-panel');
/*
panel.addEventListener('command', function(event) {
    console.log(TAG+'dropdown clicked'); //what is TAG? its undefeined for me
}, false);
*/
var label = doc.createElement('label');
label.setAttribute('control', 'name');
label.setAttribute('value', 'Article List');
var textbox = doc.createElement('textbox');
textbox.setAttribute('id', 'name');
panel.appendChild(label);
panel.appendChild(textbox);
btn.appendChild(panel);
navBar.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of arrow panels. Is there a way to place an HTML file in one rather than having to dynamically create XUL elements? The effect I'm trying to achieve is similar to the [Pocket](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/read-it-later/) extension, which does one thing when the button part is clicked and another when the arrow is clicked.

Comment: yeah append an iframe to the panel and set the iframe src

Comment: Thanks, that worked (with some modifications), but I prefer @Blargh's answer as it allows me to attach an add-on sdk panel rather than an iframe when I click the menu portion of the toolbar button. [Sorry for unaccepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon).

Comment: i agree with blargh, his solution is to your comment not to your topic question. you need to look out for that kind of stuff that stuff gets nabbed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Toolbarbutton and Panel using the Addon SDK and some Jetpack modules.  Try [toolbarwidget-jplib](https://github.com/Rob--W/toolbarwidget-jplib)  and [browser-action-jplib](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib) by Rob--W.

You can easy add a button to the toolbar and style the panel whatever you want with css / html:

```
var badge = require('browserAction').BrowserAction({
    default_icon: 'images/icon19.png', // optional
    default_title: 'Badge title',      // optional; shown in tooltip
    default_popup: 'popup.html'        // optional
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately neither provide a way to create a two-sided menu-button with two different actions depending on which side is clicked.