# Override/embed addon SDK in a Firefox extension to modify panel.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I use the Addon SDK to display a Panel. It's working fine, but I would like to set the `noautohide` property to `true`, so the panel will not closed automatically when user clicks outside the panel.

I managed to access to the panel object using ["chrome" authority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority) but I am afraid of the red mark "experimental" ;-)

So I would like to edit [`panel/utils`](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/panel/utils.js) to expose the `noautohide` property. Is it possible to "override" or "embed" my edited file in the extension package?

Comment: There was an official sdk solution we didnt realize back when we were posting solutions below. This method works: `let myPanel = Panel({.....});
let { getActiveView }=require("sdk/view/core");
getActiveView(myPanel).setAttribute("noautohide", true);` it uses the `getActiveView` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no supported way of doing this (that I know). Searching the SDK sources for `noautohide` without any results seems to confirm this.

Personally, I'd use the `require("chrome")`-and-get-the-XUL-element workaround for now (but keep in mind that there could be more than a single browser window), or just not implement it at all.

I would **advice against patching** the SDK and/or "embedding" a patched panel library.

The former would require to use a bundled SDK instead of the built-in SDK and seeing all the changes that go into each Firefox release, you'd likely have to re-package your XPI with every major Firefox update. Also you're not allowed to host add-on on [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org) that bundle a patched SDK.

The latter option of "embedding" just the panel lib has the same maintenance problems. Also, it isn't exactly easy to extract/clone the *just* the panel library from the SDK... At the very least you'd have to clone `sdk/panel.js` and `sdk/panel/*.js` maybe even more.

It might be helpful if you [filed a feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK&component=General).

Comment: noautohide is not present, thats why I want to include it (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/panel.noautohide), I believed there was a way to override AMO SDK single file by putting it on "addon-sdk" folder inside my package?

Comment: IIRC single-file override hack used to work sometimes at some point in the past, but IIRC this does not work any longer... Try it if in doubt. But as I wrote in my answer, I'd advice against patching (parts) of the SDK.

Comment: Ho ;-( ok thanks you, so to conclude, require("chrome") is fine? (It works very good BTW).

Comment: Yes, while `require("chrome")` should be avoided if possible, it is still fine to use it when it cannot be (easily) avoided, like is the case here. In fact there are tons and tons of add-ons using it (on addons.mozilla.org)

Comment: There was an official sdk solution we didnt realize back then: `let myPanel = Panel({.....});
let { getActiveView }=require("sdk/view/core");
getActiveView(myPanel).setAttribute("noautohide", true);` it uses the `getActiveView` function

Answer (score 0):

Rather than patch it what you can do is as `addEventListener` for `popuphiding` and do `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.preventDefault();`. Then just add a close button that on click removes that listener and then hides the panel. I couldn't get arouund the `noauthohide` any other way:

[Avoid panel to autoHide in Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509460/avoid-panel-to-autohide-in-firefox-extension/21599651?noredirect=1#comment32726559_21599651)

Comment: That the same thing, you need the XUL Panel object! Setting noautohide=true works fine any way.

Comment: Are you sure setting `noautohide` to true on the XUL fixed it? I tried hard to set it on a pnael made via sdk and it wouldnt understand the `noautohide`

Comment: Yes it works fine for me, do you use require("chrome") etc... to get the XUL Panel?

Comment: Yeah, well I did months ago when I helped that guy, I don't use SDK. Maybe they updated the SDK t owork right. Well thanks for the note for that, that's useful +1. Maybe you can post in that topic, or in this topic how you got the panel then how you set `noautohide`.