# best option for firefox extension to keep panel / overlay / sidebar visible between pages?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The Firefox SDK Panel disappears whenever the user interacts with the page.  Does anyone have a suggestion of the best approach that will continue to work that would allow something like a panel, overlay or sidebar to remain active as the user changes pages?

From what I've read, it looks like XUL overlays might be able to be persistent, but I'm not sure if that is something that will be supported int he future since the emphasis seems to be on the high and low level SDKs.

I'm looking to populate this panel with ajax data from my main.js (or a javascript component) - and send messages back and forth.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the panel's [noautohide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/panel.noautohide) property to true, to do that you have to access the [underlying view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#Converting_to_DOM_windows) (the linked API should also work on panels). Although in my experience that causes some annoying focusing side-effects, at least under linux.

Alternatively you could try [open a new window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#openDialog%28options%29) and with the `alwaysRaised=true,resizable,hidechrome=true,titlebar=no,close=no` flags. Although that would still have window borders, I don't know how to disable those.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like the xul panel is going to do the trick!  Your links led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509460/avoid-panel-to-autohide-in-firefox-extension - which is allowing me to have a panel that stays visible.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the first approach that you mentioned.  Would I first add the panel using the SDK, then after converting it to a DOM window change the panel's noautohide property?

Comment: You would convert it to a XUL `<panel>` with the same API

Comment: If I create the panel like this, how do I convert it to an XUL panel to change the noautohide property?
 var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: require("sdk/self").data.url("test.html"),
    position: {
        bottom: 0
    },
    width: browserWidth
});

Comment: I think for my purposes, a sidebar might be the way to go since it's stays active when the user clicks in a page.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: with `viewFor(panel)`