# ComboBox in Firefox extension via SDK not possible?

Tags: javascript, firefox, combobox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I wanted a combobox in a panel created by the FF extension API. Something like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

The SDK-tutorial says it's not possible, but a bugreport suggests a solution (the last two comments):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=918600

I also found this about setting an attribute to the panels' frame:

[Avoid panel to autoHide in Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509460/avoid-panel-to-autohide-in-firefox-extension)

Accordingly, I've tried this:

```
var prefsPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
   width: 600,
   height: 500,
   contentURL: "./prefsPanel.html",
   contentScriptFile: "./prefsPanel.js"
});

let { getActiveView } = require("sdk/view/core");
getActiveView(prefsPanel).setAttribute("tooltip", "aHTMLTooltip");
getActiveView(prefsPanel).setAttribute("noautohide", true);
```

The "noautohide"-command works, but the tooltip-command does not. Can somebody help? Tia.

Comment: In SDK, the contens of panels is just an html page, you can easily place this code in a page and load in via `contentURL`, does that work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean loading the code into a regular html-page (opened in a browser-tab) instead of a panel as I am currently trying to do?

Comment: You are loading `prefsPanel.html` right  so the combo box is in html in there?

Comment: Yes it is. The combobox is part of a regular html-document that is loaded into the panel via "contentURL". But the problem (the limitation) seems to be the frame-object containing the panel. According to the bug-report above, the way to go is to set the "tooltip"-attribute, but that doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: At least as far as the tooltip goes, your code is wrong. The line setting the `tooltip` attribute should be: `getActiveView(prefsPanel).querySelector("iframe").setAttribute("tooltip", "aHTMLTooltip");` The `tooltip` attribute needs to be on the `<iframe>` not the `<panel>`. This is per the work-around stated in the [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=918600). I have also tested it.

Comment: As for the combobox, there is no work -around mentioned in the bug report. Is this something you are still interested in? It is possible, depending on how far outside the SDK you want to go. You could implement it as XUL that you have above or below the `<iframe>`. However, you would not be interacting with it in your main script, not a content script.