# "noautohide: true" does not work on jpm Firefox add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, panel, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

How to void panel to auto-hide in Firefox Add-on SDK extension (i.e. using `jpm` for development)?

I am actually trying to develop a Firefox extension using the high level APIs, and specifically trying to avoid a panel to auto-hide when you pick a file or when you click outside of the panel itself.

Does somebody has an idea of how to do this?

I know that it is possible using XUL, so why is this not easy using the APIs?

Comment: Are you saying that the solution in: [Avoid panel to autoHide in Firefox extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21509460) does not work for you? If so, please A) explicitly state so in the question, and B) provide the code you are using (i.e. a [MCVE]).

Comment: Related: [How to show 2 sdk/panels at the same time in Firefox Add-on SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38279839)