# How to fire a panel from a panel in Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, dom-events

I have a structure like this:

```
Addon Directory
    index.js
    Data Directory
       -panel1.html
       -panel1.js
       -panel2.html
       -panel2.js
```

I defined `panel1` and `panel2` in the `index.js`. I attached `panel1` to the toolbar button. `panel1.html` contains a link that should open `panel2.html`.

The problem is:
when I call `panel2.show()` inside `panel1.js`, I get this error: `panel2.show is not a function`
This is the code:

```
var geLink= document.getElementById("mylink");
getLink.addEventListener('click', function (event)
            {
               console.log("link clicked");
                panel2.show();
                },false);
```

How to fire panel2 from panel1? is this possible?

I understand that the show method can not be invoked from outside the main addon script. So, what is the right way to show `panel2.html` and excute its content script when a link in `panel1` is clicked? is it by using using `window.open()` ?
If this is the case, how can I tell `panel2` script to not get executed until `panel2.html` window is opened? because when I tried it, `panel2` script get executed before I click the link in panel1 and before the `panel2.html` page opens.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Basically, you will need to pass a message to your main script to open panel2. There are many ways to do so. However, you should be aware: There can be **only one**  [sdk/panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel)  open at a time (that's from *all* Add-on SDK based add-ons installed in that Firefox profile, not just your add-on). Thus, you *can not* have both panel1 and panel2 open at the same time. See: [How to show 2 sdk/panels at the same time in Firefox Add-on SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38279839)

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to fire a second panel from the first panel. It is not possible to have two panels at the same time.

> Opening a panel will close any panel created by the Panel()
>   constructor that is already open, even if that panel was opened by a
>   different Add-on SDK based extension.

But, instead of a panel, you can fire a normal HTML page that contains a content script. Create a pageMod object in the index:

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: "resource://extensionfile/data/page.html",
  contentScriptFile:'./myscript.js',
  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit("going-from-index", myarray);
    worker.port.on("coming-from-panel", receivedvalue); }
});//end var pageMod
```

In the panel, listen to link click, then open the html page:

```
link = document.getElementById("click-link");
link.addEventListener('click',function (event)
                                    {
                                      window.open('page.html');
                                    }
                            );
```