# Firefox add-on : Make the panel persist when clicking on the current web document

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to make the firefox addon panel stay visible while clicking on the current document.Im using the [Toggle button attaching the panels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_toggle#Attaching_panels_to_buttons) from firefox official document.is there anyway to achieve the same.thanks in advance.

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
 id: "my-button",
 label: "my button",
 icon: {
  "16": "./icon-16.png",
  "32": "./icon-32.png",
  "64": "./icon-64.png"
 },
 onChange: handleChange
 });

 var panel = panels.Panel({
   contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
   onHide: handleHide
 });

 function handleChange(state) {
   if (state.checked) {
     panel.show({
     position: button
   });
 }
 }

 function handleHide() {
    button.state('window', {checked: false});
 }
```

Comment: You have to use `getActiveView` and then `autohide` to false - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509460/avoid-panel-to-autohide-in-firefox-extension

Comment: @Noitidart OK,when i using 'getActiveView' it wont hide anymore.i need it to hide on button toggle.
note: Its based on add-on sdk(jpm) not XUL.

Comment: @vivek, that is a new question. However, I suggest you [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#hide())

Comment: @Makyen I have tried panel.hide(); and it works on button toggle but the problem is panel persist even after the window loses its focus. for example if i open another application the panel shows right there ;(

Comment: @vivek, It sounds like you need to clearly and explicitly define when you want your panel visible and when you want it hidden. We can potentially help, but all you had previously stated was "i need it to hide on button toggle". Given that your code was already running on button toggle, I pointed you at `hide()`. You will need to determine which situations your code has to handle and which are handled for you. Keep in mind that only one Add-on SDK panel can be open at a time across all installed add-ons. If another Add-on SDK extension opens a `sdk/panel`, then your panel will close.