# Prevent firefox extension autohide when opening a file using WebExtension APIs only

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to prevent my FF extension from closing when using a button with `type="file"`.
In the past there were several workarounds and the last reported one was using the extension SDK but it has been discontinued since 2017 leaving only WebExtension API's as the only tool available to build extensions.

There was [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509460/avoid-panel-to-autohide-in-firefox-extension/21668101?noredirect=1#comment119673915_21668101) which is referenced basically everywhere but the [extension SDK has since been discontinued](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons#developing_extensions) as mentioned above.

There's also [this thread on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292701) but the latest activity was a couple months ago and prior to that 4 years ago.

Does anybody know a workaround?

### Context:

- Happens only on Firefox, Chrome works as it should
- Extension I'm working on uses min version 57
- Bug happens on desktop versions
- Been developing on Windows, haven't tried any other OS's but this seems to happen on all of them

### Steps to reproduce:

- Setup a basic firefox extension
- Add a button with `type="file"`
- Click it to load a file and set any kind of code afterwards

The extension will open the file select (as it should) but will close the extension on the background so after confirming the selection the extension will be closed and any code that should run afterwards won't work.

Any ideas or workarounds known?

Comment: Add an iframe to the current web page and point it to an html file in your extension exposed via web_accessible_resources. Work with the file there.

Comment: @wOxxOm ty for the reply, my extension interacts with tabs but not with their content ON the screen, I'd need to open a file from within the extension itself, adding content to the screen just for that would be weird and a little disruptive. But, as a fallback I guess I could make a config page for the extension with it's own HTML page as many do and add the file selection there.

Comment: The iframe doesn't have to be visible.